# Why is WKInterfaceLabel text not refreshing

Tags: objective-c, watchos-2, wkinterfacelabel

The WatchApp receives data from the iPhone.

I refresh the label text with the data received, nothing happens, the UI is not refreshing.

Other threads suggested pushing it to the main thread and that seems to do nothing either.

Any thoughts most welcome.

```
-(void)session:(nonnull WCSession *)session didReceiveApplicationContext:(nonnull NSDictionary *)applicationContext

{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.lblTitleBorH setText:@"test"];
    });
}
```

Comment: and if I put the setText statement inside -willActivate it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Are you using

```
    [*your session* updateApplicationContext:*your dictionary* error:nil];
```

correctly?

try putting a NSLog inside your above didReceiveApplicationContext code and see if it is printing anything out.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I gave up and will tackle again at some point, had higher priority stuff to do

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when I tried to refresh the UI, I found that the outlet references were `nil`. The problem was caused by two interfaces on the storyboard, belonging to the same `WKInterfaceController` class.
When I assigned the second screen interface to another WKInterfaceController class it worked fine.

[image]

remember to call the UI objects from the main thread by using

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   ...
});
```

or by using methods like `performSelectorOnMainThread: withObject: waitUntilDone:`